# Different Python Version/Environment Per Directory in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a project that includes multiple major Python components (apps that run independently) with differing dependencies and even Python versions (not ideal, but we're working on it). Each component has its own `venv` subdirectory which it should use for its full Python environment. What I'd like to be able to do is launch Visual Studio Code from the root of the repository (which doesn't have a `venv`) and have it recognize that for the purpose of linting (and any other code checking) it should use `component1\venv` as the Python environment/interpreter for any files that live under the `component1` directory, but use `component2\venv` for any files that live under the `component2` directory.

Currently, I can run `code component1` or `code component2` if I only want to work on a single component at a time (both have their own `.vscode` directories with python environment settings), but if I want to be able to work on multiple components (and other files that live in the root directory of the repo), Visual Studio Code uses a different Python environment (I think the system default) for everything, regardless of directory.

I've looked at related questions here, but if they suggest a solution to this, I'm missing it. If I could set different `"python.pythonPath"` settings per subdirectory in the root `.vscode/settings.json` file, that would probably do it, but I don't see a way to do that. Alternatively, if the settings were overridden by more local settings in subdirectories, it would already be working (each subdirectory already has a `.vscode/settings.json` that sets its correct `"python.pythonPath"`). Maybe this just isn't possible right now?

(Note: at the moment I'm not even concerned about actually running the components in the debugger...just getting basic coding tools and the "Problems" tab to work correctly.)

Answer (score 3):

I believe you're after a [multi-root workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces) with each individual workspace configured as appropriate.

Comment: It's possible that a multi-root workspace would work for this, but I'm still trying to figure out how. Specifically, if I create a multi-root workspace, I can include the various component directories, but then it excludes the files in the parent directory (including the workspace file itself), which I do need access to in the editor. I can add "." as a folder, which generally seems to work, but it also recreates the entire directory structure (meaning my component subfolders exist in redundant locations, and only one works correctly), which is pretty ugly. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CoryMcCarty I don't think you're missing anything, you're just after support for a directory structure that VS Code simply doesn't support. Best I can think of is to move the files you want to have at a higher level directory to a separate directory next to your sub-directories so it's just like any other folder in your multi-root workspace.

Answer (score 3):

This was something we had to figure out recently when we switched to VS Code. We couldn't find any easy answers elsewhere. For anyone else coming across this still, the easiest solution for us was the following:

1. Open the repository in VS Code
2. In the .vscode/settings.json file exclude directories using separate virtual envs:

```
"files.exclude": {
    "src/package1": true,
    "src/package2": true,
  }
```

3. Add each package as a folder to the workpsace. You can use alias's via the `name` property if that helps make it more clear for your team.
4. In the `.vscode/settings.json` file for each package added to the workspace you can set the default interpreter to the local virtual env.

```
"python.defaultInterpreterPath": "${workspaceFolder}/.venv/bin/python"
```

After doing this we are able to have separate virtual environments, debug, and have the language server for each package resolve imports correctly.